# Dispatch redux action before render with react hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

So, as the title says: how can we dispatch a redux action before rendering a component?

I have a specific case where i need some shared state chunk cleared before component renders (in that case showing “loading...”) which is done through dispatching redux action.

Now, if i dispatch it with `useEffect` i get flickering of first stale/old data shown and then showing “loading...”.

So far i see 2 ways to solve it:

1. `useLayoutEffect` - i like it but not sure if its a good practice
2. redefine redux model - that one i would like to avoid plus it sounds a bit wierd

I might create custom `Fetcher` hook but doesnt that bring it back into realm of hocs/wrapper hells?

I just want to do something before first render.

Comment: If flickering is the only issue then useLayoutEffect is a way to go.

Comment: @estus thanks for your comment! could you please post it as answer so i could accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference between `useEffect` and `useLayoutEffect` is that the latter is executed synchronously after initial render:

> The signature is identical to useEffect, but it fires synchronously after all DOM mutations. Use this to read layout from the DOM and synchronously re-render. Updates scheduled inside useLayoutEffect will be flushed synchronously, before the browser has a chance to paint.

If flickering is the only problem with `useEffect` and it disappears with `useLayoutEffect` then the latter should be used.